# C - error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'

Tags: c

I'm learning C, and was trying to create an ArrayList for practice.  When I try to compile this code, I get quite a few errors, but I can't figure out why I am getting this:

Test.c:12:13: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
 struct init(void);

There wasn't much on google about this error in connection to void, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct ArrayList {
    int size;
    int typeSize;
    int index;
    int array[];
};

struct init(void);

void add(struct list, int x);

int get(struct list, int x);


int main() {
   struct ArrayList list = init();
   add(list, 4);
   printf("%d", get(list, 0));
   return 0;
}


struct init(void) {
    ArrayList this;
    this.size = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
}

void add(struct list, int x) {
    list->array[size] = x;
    size++;
}

int get(struct list, int index) {
    return list->array[index];
}
```

Comment: BTW `list->array[size] = x;` : Area has not been secured.

Comment: and replace `struct list` with `struct ArrayList *list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct name is missing.

```
struct ArrayList init(void);

struct ArrayList init(void) {
    ArrayList this;
    this.size = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
}
```

The other problem, `array` is not initialized in you case, it would be undefined behavior to use it in `add` and `get`:

```
struct ArrayList init(void) {
    ArrayList this;
    this.size = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
}
```

In this case the flexible array member `array` are not associated with any storage, it is better to do this instead:

```
struct ArrayList* init(void) {
    ArrayList *this = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayList) + sizeof(int[NUM]));
    this->size = NUM;
    this->index = 0;
    return this;
}
```

The `add` and `get` function needs to be fixed too:

```
void add(struct ArrayList *list, int x) {
    list->array[list->index++] = x;
}

int get(struct ArrayList *list, int index) {
    return list->array[index];
}
```

Comment: `this.array = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));` can't compile. `this.array` is flexible array, not pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you are right, the whole struct needs to be allocated with the storage for the array, `struct ArrayList list * = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayList) + sizeof (int[size]));` but the OP's `init` returns a struct, not a pointer, it would make this difficult.

Comment: probably, `this.size = 0;` --> `this->size = NUM;`, `list->array[size] = x;` --> `list->array[list->index++] = x;` and Need range check and expand.

Comment: fixed, copy-pasted that part :(

Comment: Of course, They(range check and expand) are  only mentioned. You do not implement.

Comment: What does "expand" mean here?

Comment: There is a need to extend when  became a capacity full.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct init(void);
```

This is a syntax error.

Given the type declaration `struct ArrayList { ... }`, the name of the type is `struct ArrayList`. If `init` is supposed to return an `ArrayList` structure, it needs to be declared as:

```
struct ArrayList init(void);
```

You also have an error in the definition of the `init` function. This declaration:

```
ArrayList this;
```

needs to be:

```
struct ArrayList this;
```

(As a style point, you might consider using a name other than `this`. In C++, `this` is a keyword, and you're using as an identifier in a way that's inconsistent with its C++ meaning. That's perfectly legal, but it might cause some confusion. I suggest calling it `result`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct init(void);
```

struct isn't a sufficient type on its own. You may want to use something like this instead:

```
struct ArrayList init(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct init(void);` -- it looks like a function without arguments that returns a `struct`. But what `struct`? Probably `struct ArrayList`.

The same for the rest of appearances of `struct` without a name of a `struct` type.

Answer (score 0):

You have so many error in your data types ..**struct is not the data type**. Check this. I already changed your code. Remember if you're going to use pointers you should at least pass the address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ArrayList {
int size;
int typeSize;
int index;
int *array;
};

struct ArrayList init();

void add(struct ArrayList* list, int x);

int get(struct ArrayList* list, int x);


int main() {
   struct ArrayList list = init();
   add(&list, 4);
   printf("%d", get(&list, 0));
   return 0;
}


struct ArrayList init() {
   struct ArrayList this;
   this.size = 0;
   this.index = 0;
   this.array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * /*numOfelementsToBeInserted*/);
   return this;
}

void add(struct ArrayList *list, int x) {
    list->array[list->size] = x;
    list->size++;
}

int get(struct ArrayList *list, int index) {
    return list->array[index];
 }
```

Comment: I've modified my code, and it is similar to what you posted here.  One thing I changed was that I made the array[] in struct into int *array.  I get the expected output, but I also get "test.exe has stopped working" error, and through debugging, I've found that this happens on your first line of add.  Any idea why?

Comment: if you changed your **structure from array[] to int *array** you still need to allocate space for that to be fiiled with elements

Comment: I added this:     struct ArrayList *newList = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayList) + sizeof(int) * 20);  I believe this allocates space for the int *, correct?

Comment: **struct ArrayList***   newList = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayList) + sizeof(int) * 20)
It allocates in the heap a space for a data type struct ArrayList pointer